# wordpress custom theme with custom post - hide the button if no post

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I've tried different codes from the internet but nothing can help me in my problem. I have a Wordpress custom theme with custom post. on my top/home page there is a News container where the top 3 current News are posted, from this container there is a one [View More] button which linked to the News Page. I am trying to hide the [View More] button if there are no News posted and will echoed a text saying "there are no post at this time". and if there new News Posted, the [View More] button will show up. this function will solve through php? I am still not good in Php, can someone help me do this? here is my current custom post:

```
 <?php
   $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'post',
   'posts_per_page' => 3,
   'category_name' => 'news',
   'orderby' => 'post_date',
   'order' => 'DESC',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   );
   $posts = get_posts( $args );
   foreach ( $posts as $post ):
   setup_postdata( $post );
 ?>  

 <div class="newbox">
     <div class="newimg">
     <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
     <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-img'); ?>
     <?php else : ?>
                                            
     <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/image/default-img.png">
    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
     <h3 class="title1"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
     <p class="cont"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
     <p class="date"><?php the_time('Y.m.d'); ?></p>

     <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
       <h5 class="btnmr">Read</h5>
     </a>
 </div>

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>  

<!-- VIEW MORE -->
 <div class="col-lg-12">
     <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/post/newspage' ) ); ?>">
         <div class="btn-default1">
            <p>VIEW MORE</p>
         </div> 
      </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `WP_Query` class where you can get total posts using `found_posts`. try the below code.

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 3,
    'category_name'  => 'news',
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
);

$posts     = get_posts( $args );
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$totalpost = $the_query->found_posts; 

foreach ( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ); ?>  

    <div class="newbox">
        <div class="newimg">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) : ?>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('small-img'); ?>
            <?php else : ?>                                    
                <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/image/default-img.png">
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
        <h3 class="title1"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <p class="cont"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
        <p class="date"><?php the_time('Y.m.d'); ?></p>
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <h5 class="btnmr">Read</h5>
        </a>
    </div>

<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>  

<!-- VIEW MORE -->
<?php if( $totalpost > $args['posts_per_page'] ){ ?>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/post/newspage' ) ); ?>">
            <div class="btn-default1">
                <p>VIEW MORE</p>
            </div> 
        </a>
    </div>
<?php }else{
    echo "No post this time";
} ?>
```

Comment: hi @Bhautik I tried your code above but the result was, even there has a post the VIEW MORE button was not showed. and if I removed the post, there are no text echo saying "No post this time"

Comment: the echo text is showed up even there is a post, also the view more button is hidden even there is a post